# Get all rotations for a string in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to make a function "rot" which takes a string and returns a list of strings with all possible rotations, e.g rot "abc" returns ["abc", "bca", cab"], seems very simple to do in other languages but I'm a newbie at haskell so I can't think of a way to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
rot :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
rot word = 
    let
        lst = [tail word ++ [head word]]
    in
        lst
    

main = do
    print(rot "abc")
```

It returns me "bca" as expected, but I would like a way to find all rotations and store it in a list.

Here's an example in python

```
def rot(word):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        newWord1 = word[0:i]
        newWord2 = word[i:]
        newWordResult = newWord2 + newWord1
        lst.append(newWordResult)
    return lst
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would do it in other languages?

Comment: I added a python example to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can more or less directly translate your Python code. Recursion is customarily used in functional programming instead of iteration, and it's more convenient to count from `length word` down to zero. Other than that, it's pretty much the same:

```
rot word =
  let loop 0 lst = lst
      loop i lst =
        let newWord1 = take (i-1) word
            newWord2 = drop (i-1) word
            newWordResult = newWord2 ++ newWord1
        in loop (i-1) (newWordResult : lst)

  in loop (length word) []
```

Comment: Mate, thank you so much! This explanation not only answered my question but also made me understand "let" expressions much better! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: *"e.g `rot "abc"` returns `["abc", "bca", cab"]`"* does not hold. or maybe the OP doesn't care about the actual order...

Comment: @WillNess ah, one of the three hard problems in software! :-)

Comment: Fixed it. At first I thought to leave that as an exercise for the reader, but then my OCD won out.

Answer (score 3):

One can make use of the `tails` and `inits` of a list:

```
Prelude Data.List> tails "abc"
["abc","bc","c",""]
Prelude Data.List> inits "abc"
["","a","ab","abc"]
```

we thus can use this with:

```
import Data.List(inits, tails)

rotated :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotated xs = [x ++ y | (x@(_:_), y) <- zip (tails xs) (inits xs)]
```

This produces:

```
Prelude Data.List> rotated "abc"
["abc","bca","cab"]
Prelude Data.List> rotated [1,4,2,5]
[[1,4,2,5],[4,2,5,1],[2,5,1,4],[5,1,4,2]]
Prelude Data.List> rotated [1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
[[1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0],[3.0,0.0,2.0,1.0],[0.0,2.0,1.0,3.0],[2.0,1.0,3.0,0.0]]
```

or as [@Iceland_jack says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573669/get-all-rotations-for-a-string-in-haskell/64576828?noredirect=1#comment114221226_64576828), we can use the [**`ParallelListComp`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ParallelListComp) extension to allow iterating over two lists in parallel in list comprehension without the explicit use of `zip`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

import Data.List(inits, tails)

rotated :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotated xs = [x ++ y | x@(_:_) <- tails xs | y <- inits xs]
```

Comment: [`-XParallelLispComp`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/parallel_list_comprehensions.html?highlight=parallellistcomp#extension-ParallelListComp) lets you write `[ x ++ y | x@(_:_) <- tails xs | y <- inits xs ]`

Comment: You can also use `init` instead of that weird pattern match, but since `init` does not (yet?) interact with list fusion, your way is probably faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is, simply,

```
rotations xs = map (take n) . take n
                 . tails $ xs ++ xs
   where
   n = length xs
```

It is customary to avoid `length` if at all possible, though *here* it leads to a bit more convoluted code<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> (but more often than not it leads to a simpler, cleaner code that is more true to the true nature of the problem),

```
rotations2 xs = map (zipWith (\a b -> b) xs) 
                 . zipWith (\a b -> b) xs
                 . tails $ xs ++ xs
```

Testing, we get

```
> rotations "abcd"
["abcd","bcda","cdab","dabc"]

> rotations2 "abcd"
["abcd","bcda","cdab","dabc"]

> take 4 . map (take 4) $ rotations2 [1..]
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]
```

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> *edit* Actually, it probably merits its own name,

```
takeLength :: [a] -> [b] -> [b]
takeLength  =  zipWith (\a b -> b)

rotations2 xs = map (takeLength xs) 
                 . takeLength xs
                 . tails $ xs ++ xs
```